# Openstack create new instance of Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, instance, openstack

I am new to Openstack, and after a complete installation of it in Ubuntu,now I am trying to create a new instance of Ubuntu OS via dashboard (horizon). Now, the ISO image that I have selected for the same has been in queued state since a long time, for about 30 minutes.

Could any one tell me how long does it take? I have tried another option of using a .vdi file, but that too took a lot of time before I eventually canceled the operation.

Comment: Check logs. There might be a problem. It should be completed with in 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Check nova-compute logs.

If still problem exists then check nova.conf in /etc/nova/nova.conf and change

> virt-type to QEMU

if your machine lacks acceleration.

To check acceleration use kvm-ok command.